# High CPU usage in Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, totem

Since I installed this version, I have a slow computer. When I use Firefox, sometimes CPU usage exceeds 100%, but when I use Totem or VLC with 1080p videos, CPU usage exceeds 300%.

My computer is a Intel Core i5 2430m 2.4 GHz, 4 GB ram and a 2 GB dedicated NVIDIA graphics card.

I have deactivated Compiz special effects. But I don't know what to do now.

`top`:

```
10101 ppito     20   0 2196704 164884  63072 S 313,6  4,2   1:45.42 totem                        
 3523 root      20   0  383012  12792   8044 S   7,0  0,3   0:01.46 udisksd                      
 3520 ppito     20   0 1614172 268484  60164 S   5,6  6,8   7:41.96 compiz                       
 2648 root      20   0  509284  78140  64672 S   4,7  2,0  14:56.02 Xorg                         
 3431 ppito      9 -11  442532  13216  10100 S   1,7  0,3   2:20.65 pulseaudio                   
 8662 ppito     20   0 1198868 375380 109908 S   1,7  9,5   2:54.29 firefox
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @Pilot6 - The problem is (again) not having the proper drivers for the "2gb dedicated nvidia graphic card" ;-)

Comment: slow computer is a problem..

Comment: Yes, i tried to use the propietary drivers but doesnt' work for me

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `top` output it appears the CPU is running at 313% which is impossible right?:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
10101 ppito     20   0 2196704 164884  63072 S 313,6  4,2   1:45.42 totem
```

By default `top` adds up all your CPU percentages. Your i5 has 4 CPUs so the actual percentage is approximately 313/4 or 79% CPU utilization. This is still phenomenally high. To get `top` to show a an average percentage of all CPUs type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

Googling `high cpu usage totem` returns many results which you can try. There are too many to include in this answer.

If none of the solutions presented by other `totem` users work I would suggest an update to Kernel 4.7.3 which reduced CPU usage for me versus Kernel 4.4 that Ubuntu ships with.

You might want to update your question with additional `top` output when **firefox** is running at a high CPU percentage and comments about what you were doing at the time, ie watching video or flash player in **firefox**.

As commented by @Pilot6, "And what is the problem?" you never responded with reports of "choppy video", or "loud fan", "high temperature" or anything like that. If your machine is running ok there really isn't a problem other than 313% CPU usage which is impossible and which I hopefully explained is misleading within `top` before pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Yes, choppy video and loud fan occurs. I have a problem with the nvidia driver but i don't find the solution